# Export functions under other name

Tags: node.js

I want to do something like

```
export { getDocs: getCollectionData, addDoc: addDocToCollection };
```

What's the right syntax for this?

Comment: Have you tried using `as`? Ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#:~:text=export%20%7B%20variable1%20as%20name1%2C%20variable2%20as%20name2%2C%20%E2%80%A6%2C%20nameN%20%7D%3B)

Answer (score 5):

You're very close! Use the `as` keyword to [rename the exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export):

```js
export { getCollectionData as getDocs, addDocToCollection as addDoc };
```

Comment: Ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#:~:text=export%20%7B%20variable1%20as%20name1%2C%20variable2%20as%20name2%2C%20%E2%80%A6%2C%20nameN%20%7D%3B)